# Jmeter Uploading files using multiple threads

Tags: jmeter

I want to test file uploading using Jmeter.

I want to upload files using 5 threads concurrently.

1 Thread successfully uploads all the files but after that all threads says file exist (which makes sense)

Is there a way i can upload all files successfully from all 5 threads, may be generate new file name each time ?

[image]

Comment: I was able to rename the file before uploading it using a beanshell code. In my case there was only 1 file though. Also this way it will rename the file on your machine, so you might need to go back to the files and rename them again before/after each test, will that work with you? If yes, are you going to run the scripts from your local machine?

Comment: I see you are suggesting some manual stuff...can it not be automated by beanshell code which will rename each file for every user and upload it ? Yes i am running from local machine

Comment: The manual stuff is more like test data organizing, renaming the files to be something like file_1.pdf, file_2.pdf, file_3.xlsx ...etc. Another concern to my solution is that you will not be able to upload the files with 5 concurrent users at the same time, but one at a time, reason is that when 2 or more threads are renaming the files at the same time, only the last thread will find the files (because it will be renamed from file_1.pdf to file_5.pdf) so the other 4 threads will fail. To fix that, you will need separate files for each thread (a copy with different name will work).

Answer (score 2):

This solution will work for the configurations that you shared, **5 concurrent users** uploading **10 files** each.

First of all, create separate files for each thread (you have 10 files, copy them into 50) and rename them as below

```
Thread1_file1_0
Thread1_file2_0
Thread1_file3_0
.
.
Thread1_file10_0
Thread2_file1_0
Thread2_file2_0
.
.
Thread5_file10_0
```

Then create a **csv file** and add file extensions in column A. Make sure that `row 1` reflects the extension of `Threadx_file1_0` and `row 2` reflects the extension of `Threadx_file2_0` file as below and save the csv file in the same folder of your jmx script

[image]

Now to the script configurations, add 2 [counters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) before your POST request (which uploads the files) with below configurations

**First counter**

Start `0`

Increment `1`

Reference Name `originalName`

Track counter independently for each user `Yes`

Reset counter on each Thread Group Iteration `No`

**Second counter**

Start `1`

Increment `1`

Reference Name `Iteration`

Track counter independently for each user `Yes`

Reset counter on each Thread Group Iteration `No`

Now add a [loop controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with loop count set to `10`, then add another **counter**, [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) and [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) as children of the loop controller with below configurations

**Counter configurations**

Start `1`

Increment `1`

Reference Name `fileNumber`

Track counter independently for each user `Yes`

Reset counter on each Thread Group Iteration `Yes`

**CSV Data Set Config**

Filename `extensionsCSVFile.csv`

Variable Names `extension`

**OS Process Sampler configurations**

Command `cmd`

Command parameters

```
/C

ren {path to your folder}\Thread${__threadNum}_file${fileNumber}_${originalName}.${extension} Thread${__threadNum}_file${fileNumber}_${Iteration}.${extension}
```

Each line as a separate parameter. Now use file name in your post request as below

```
{path}\Thread${__threadNum}_file1_${Iteration}.pdf
{path}\Thread${__threadNum}_file2_${Iteration}.pdf
.
.
{path}\Thread${__threadNum}_file10_${Iteration}.docx
```

This will do the job, but i suggest that you also add a way to revert the names back to `Thread1_file1_0`. You can do it by following the below steps

Add a [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the **OS Process Sampler** with below code in the code area

```
props.put("lastIteration", vars.get("Iteration"));
```

Now add a [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group), then copy the **loop controller** with all its elements from previous above steps and paste into the **tearDown Thread Group** (except the **BeanShell PostProcessor**, remove it after you paste).

Now go the **OS Process Sampler** within the **tearDown Thread Group** and adjust the second parameter as below

```
ren {}\Thread${__threadNum}_file${fileNumber}_${__P(lastIteration)}.${extension} Thread${__threadNum}_file${fileNumber}_0.${extension}
```

Finally, just make sure that number of threads in both **main thread group** and **tearDown Thread Group** is the same, which in this case `5`. The structure will be as below

[image]